# Figuring out when images are loaded after they are inserted using jQuery.load('url.html')

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I currently have something similar to this, it loads a div on the target page that has images in it.

```
$('a.galleryNext').click(function(){
    // chnage the image to loading
    $("#info").html("LOADING");
    $("#currentGal").load("gallery.php div#gallery"+currentgallery, function(){
        //this fires much too early, the images are still loading...
        $("#info").html("DONE");
    });
});
```

What I cannot figure out is how to change #info into something else after the images in the div are done loading (which happens after the load returns the html). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what you need. I use it all the time at work for loading huge maps and its really easy to use.

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

Comment: This answer is of no use now as the link is broken.
You should have added a short description describing the solution

Answer (score 2):

I like to use classes to control a loading/done gif by background-image

Also your load() syntax looked off. see: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

```
<style>

.done { background-image:done.gif; }
.loading { background-image:loading.gif; }

</style>
<script>
    $('a.galleryNext').click(function(){

        $("#info").addClass("loading");
        $("#info").removeClass("done");
        $("#currentGal").load("gallery.php", null, function(){

            $("#info").removeClass("loading");
            $("#info").addClass("done");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="currentGal"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: ya... it might be, I just stripped a bunch of stuff out of it to give the gist of it.

Comment: That callback function in this code, Lance Rushing, still executes before inserted images are fully loaded. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The callback is checking that content is returned - meaning the markup is returned. You'll have to do a different check to see if the images are downloaded.

You'll have to enumerate the images in the html and check if they have been loaded.

Perhaps a solution would be getting the count of images, and incrementing a loaded counter each time an image loaded, using the .load callback function. When the loaded count matches the image count, then all content is ready.

Looks like this could be of assistance to you:

[Waiting for images loading with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098788/waiting-for-images-loading-with-jquery)

**EDIT**

Here is a working solution, in FF. Not sure if this is the best way, or how it works in IE, but you get the idea.

```
        var $images = $("#somediv img");
        if ($images.length) {

            var imageCount = $images.length;
            var imageLoadedCount = 0;

            $images.each(function() {
                $(this).load(function() {
                    imageLoadedCount += 1;
                });
            });

            var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                if (imageCount == imageLoadedCount) {
                    //console.log("all loaded");
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                };
            }, 200);


        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted this very simple function from some code I found on another forum. It includes a callback function for you to use when the images have finished loading.

```
function imgsLoaded(el,f){
  var imgs = el.find('img');
  var num_imgs = imgs.length;

  if(num_imgs > 0){
    imgs.load(function(){
      num_imgs--;
      if(num_imgs == 0) {
        if(typeof f == "function")f();//custom callback
      }
    });
  }else{
    if(typeof f == "function")f();//custom callback
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```
imgsLoaded($('#container'),function(){

//stuff to do after imgs have loaded

});
```

Hope this helps!

W.

Comment: wow, cool, that almost exactly like my function. see my answer. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I just came up with:

```
function when_images_loaded($img_container, callback) { //do callback when images in $img_container are loaded. Only works when ALL images in $img_container are newly inserted images.
    var img_length = $img_container.find('img').length,
        img_load_cntr = 0;

    if (img_length) { //if the $img_container contains new images.
        $('img').load(function() { //then we avoid the callback until images are loaded
            img_load_cntr++;
            if (img_load_cntr == img_length) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
    else { //otherwise just do the main callback action if there's no images in $img_container.
        callback();
    }
```

}

Coincidentally, it is almost identical to pagewil's answer, but I came up with mine on my own. ;D

Use this function after you .load() content into a container.

e.g.:

```
$("#foobar").load("gallery.php", null, function(){
    when_images_loaded($("#foobar"), function(){
        $("#info").removeClass("loading");
        $("#info").addClass("done");
    });
});
```