# jQuery event for images being "displayable"

Tags: jquery, image, events, load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Waiting for images loading with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098788/waiting-for-images-loading-with-jquery)

I've a big problem which is never really answered in any post I found on the internet, so here's my question:

What is the right event if I want to execute some code as soon as an image is "displayable"? It's kind of the one called "load", but actually the .load() event is triggered some period before. In my case I want to animate the loaded image, but at the beginning (especially on mobile devices) the image is being animated without being displayed/rendered completely.

```
somecontainer.children("img").load(function() {
    $(this).parent().data('loaded', 'true');
};

somecontainer.children("img").click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().data('loaded') == 'true')
        $(this).animate({
            left: var1,
            top: var2,
            width: var3
        });
});
```

As you see, I bound the animation on the "load" event indirectly (and also tried stuff like the jQuery Plugin "waitforimages"), none of them really worked. How can I get the event I want? There has to be any way, right?

Best wishes & thanks in advance,
Dennis

EDIT: Correcting code

Comment: In my case the `.load()` -event is triggered, but too early. In addition to this, the mentioned Plugin "waitforimages" does check the `complete` value as well and it doesn't work... :-/
So I think it's not the same.

Comment: Do you have multiple images, and how are they replated to `picture_large`? Your function will execute when each image is loaded. If `picture_large` isn't the first one, the animation will start too early for it. Maybe you should be using `$(this)` to access the appropriate image.

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry, this was my fault. It is definately the right image. In fact I set a parameter (in somecontainer.data()) to true when the image did load. In a "click" eventhandler I execute the animation in case the parameter is true, so there is not the problem. I'll edit my post to make this clear...

Comment: Honestly, the "duplicate" is in no way the same problem since in the other thread he says his event is NOT fired and in my problem the event is fired too early in case of big images. I have no idea why this post got closed, but with behavoiur like this I'll never get an answer...

Comment: I realized that too late, I've nominated it for reopening.